# Ruby on Rails 3 Partial Pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For a certain employee I have a report. Each report has some shifts. Each shift can be corrected. I am migrating from Ruby 2 to Ruby 3. I am working with partial pages. When I click on Correct, a partial page appears, when I click on Update, page should go back to the partial page Details with the ID of that employee.

_modify_item.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :modified_item, :url => {:action => :modify_item, :report_id => @monthly_report.id, :modified_item_id => @modified_item.id,remote: true}  do |form| %>

<table width=100% height=100%>
<td width=150 style='border: 0px; background-color: #eee' align=center>
        <%= form.hidden_field :report_id, :value => @monthly_report.id %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Update', :name => 'update', :value => 'Update', :class => 'highlighted_button' %>

        <%= link_to 'Cancel',
                    {:action => 'details', :report_id => @monthly_report.id},
                    :class => 'highlighted_button',
                    remote: true %>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<% end %>
```

controller.rb:

```
def modify_item
        @modified_item = Employee::MonthlyReportItem.find(params[:modified_item_id])
        @monthly_report = @modified_item.report
        begin
            @modified_item.update_attributes!(params[:modified_item])
            flash[:notice] = 'Position was updated.'
            flash[:warning]=@modified_item.verification_problems if !@modified_item.correct? 
            redirect_to('/accounts/salary/details', :report_id => @monthly_report.id) and return
        rescue Exception => e
            flash.now[:error] = "Some of the values are missing or are incorrect. Try again."
        end
        #render(:partial => 'details') and return
    end
```

modify_item.js.erb: (tried didn't succeed)

```
//$("#salary_popup").html("<%= j(render partial: 'details') %>");
```

Update: Forgot to mention the exact error which points inside of the if

```
Couldn't find Employee::MonthlyReport without an ID
```

Rails goes into details function and tries this:

```
def details
        if params[:item].nil?
            @monthly_report = Employee::MonthlyReport.find(params[:report_id])
        else
            @monthly_report = Employee::MonthlyReport.find(params[:item][:report_id])
        end
..
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the hidden field you create have the name attribute? If not trying adding that.